# Is AWS Lambda good for real-time API Rest?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I'm learning about AWS Lambda and I'm worried about synchronized real-time requests. 
The fact the lambda has a "cold start" it doesn't sounds good for handling GET petitions.

Imagine a user is using the application and do a GET HTTP Request to get a Product or a list of Products, if the lambda is sleeping, then it will take 10 seconds to respond, I don't see this as an acceptable response time.
Is it good or bad practice to use AWS Lambda for classic (sync responses) API Rest?

Comment: *"it will take 10 seconds to respond"* – Where'd you get *that* idea? It takes ~200ms to wake up, not 10 seconds.

Comment: @deceze Well you're right, maybe not 10 seconds but in some articles it says 1,5 sec like this one https://medium.freecodecamp.org/lambda-vpc-cold-starts-a-latency-killer-5408323278dd. The question is, is it good or bad for those type of operations?

Comment: "Realtime", "slow" are subjective terms. For different kinds of applications, the overhead of Lambda can be acceptable or not. So your question is invalid I think. Most importantly, the internet itself is not "realtime", and the network latency is unpredictable in general.

Comment: Well, generally the lambda execution model is *perfect* for stateless HTTP requests. Whether it fits *your* use case you need to decide. As that article states, *in certain configurations* there can be additional overhead producing latency. Whether you use those certain configurations or not you decide. Whether you can live with a few seconds of cold start or not you decide. How often users will encounter cold starts, only you know (the more visitors you have the rarer they are).

Comment: Lambda have cold start. It can take seconds to start. I can take up to 10s to start if you have configure the lambda to be in a VPC (it take time for a Network Interface to be created). One solution is to keep the lambda warm, by creating a scheduled task with cloudwatch that trigger a lambda with an empty payload. Whatever Lambda took seconds to start, it's not usable for realtime in any case. Better go to full blown Websocket server or SNS, or even..... AWS IoT.

Comment: Note that VPC Lambda startup times have improved substantially per https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-improved-vpc-networking-for-aws-lambda-functions/. The example provided suggests a reduction from 10s to sub 1s.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Like most things, I think you should measure before deciding. A lot of AWS customers use Lambda as the back-end for their webapps quite successfully.

There's a lot of discussion out there on Lambda latency, for example:

- [2017-04 comparing Lambda performance using Node.js, Java, C# or Python](https://read.acloud.guru/comparing-aws-lambda-performance-when-using-node-js-java-c-or-python-281bef2c740f)
- [2018-03 Lambda call latency](https://forum.serverless.com/t/lambda-call-latency/3891/11)
- [2019-09 improved VPC networking for AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-improved-vpc-networking-for-aws-lambda-functions/)
- [2019-10 you're thinking about cold starts all wrong](https://hackernoon.com/im-afraid-you-re-thinking-about-aws-lambda-cold-starts-all-wrong-7d907f278a4f)

In December 2019, AWS Lambda introduced Provisioned Concurrency, which improves things. See:

- [2019-12 AWS Lambda announces Provisioned Concurrency](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/12/aws-lambda-announces-provisioned-concurrency/)
- [2020-09 AWS Lambda Cold Starts: Solving the Problem](https://lumigo.io/blog/this-is-all-you-need-to-know-about-lambda-cold-starts/)

You should measure latency for an environment that's representative of your app and its use.

A few things that are important factors related to request latency:

- cold starts => higher latency
- request patterns are important factors in cold starts
- if you need to deploy in VPC (attachment of ENI => higher cold start latency)
- using CloudFront --> API Gateway --> Lambda (more layers => higher latency)
- choice of programming language (Java likely highest cold-start latency, Go lowest)
- size of Lambda environment (more RAM => more CPU => faster)
- Lambda account and concurrency limits
- pre-warming strategy

Update 2019-12: see [Predictable start-up times with Provisioned Concurrency](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-for-aws-lambda-predictable-start-up-times-with-provisioned-concurrency/).

Update 2021-08: see [Increasing performance of Java AWS Lambda functions using tiered compilation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/increasing-performance-of-java-aws-lambda-functions-using-tiered-compilation/).

Answer (score 8):

As an AWS Lambda + API Gateway user (with Serverless Framework) I had to deal with this too.

**The problem I faced:**

- Few requests per day per lambda (not enough to keep lambdas warm)
- Time critical application (the user is on the phone, waiting for text-to-speech to answer)

**How I worked around that:**

The idea was to find a way to call the critical lambdas often enough that they don't get cold.
If you use the Serverless Framework, you can use the [serverless-plugin-warmup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-plugin-warmup) plugin that does exactly that.
If not, you can copy it's behavior by creating a worker that will invoke the lambdas every few minutes to keep them warm. To do this, create a lambda that will invoke your other lambdas and schedule CloudWatch to trigger it every 5 minutes or so. Make sure to call your to-keep-warm lambdas with a custom `event.source` so you can exit them early without running any actual business code by putting the following code at the very beginning of the function:

```
if (event.source === 'just-keeping-warm) {
  console.log('WarmUP - Lambda is warm!');
  return callback(null, 'Lambda is warm!');
}
```

Depending on the number of lamdas you have to keep warm, this can be a lot of "warming" calls. AWS offers [1.000.000 free lambda calls](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/?nc1=h_ls) every month though.

Comment: In other words, you used hacks, doing things to make lambda handle what is was not designed to handle.

Comment: @Donato it’s just keeping the functions warm. It works very well and this practice is widespread in the Serverless community.

Comment: It may be a hack, but it's certainly unfair to say lambdas aren't designed to handle multiple requests.

Comment: I don't understand why you would keep your lambda warm. If you need `always on` then go with IIS, nginx, Apache servers to handle API calls.

Comment: @JobaDiniz because it's basically free and virtually zero maintenance

Comment: but if you have dozen, or hundreds (very plausible for APIs), would keeping all of them warm be cheaper than other services or containers (always on)? *I don't know, I'm just posing the question.*

Comment: @JobaDiniz the free tier of AWS is 1.000.000 invocations per month. And then it's still very cheap.

Answer (score 2):

We have used AWS Lambda quite successfully with reasonable and acceptable response times. (REST/JSON based API + AWS Lambda + Dynamo DB Access).

The latency that we measured always had the least amount of time spent in invoking functions and large amount of time in application logic.

There are warm up techniques as mentioned in the above posts.